# how can i sort the nested dictionary by keys alphabetically

Tags: python-3.x

How can I sort the nested dictionary by keys alphabetically? In other words, I want my dictionary to be sorted in lexicographic order.

My code that makes dictionaries :

```
from collections import *
with open('Input_1.txt', 'r') as file:
    dict_2 = {}
    for line in file:
        surname, item, amount = line.split()
        amount = int(amount)
        if surname not in dict_2:
            dict_2[surname] = {}
        if item not in dict_2[surname]:
            dict_2[surname][item] = amount
        else:
            dict_2[surname][item] += amount
```

I tried to sort it with this code:

```
dict_2 = { key : dict_2[key]  for key in sorted(dict_2) } 
    print(dict_2)
```

here is what it prints:

```
{'Ivanov': {'aaa': 52, 'bbb': 3, 'ccc': 45, 'paper': 17, 'marker': 3, 'envelope': 5},   'Petrov': {'aaa': 9, 'bbb': 7, 'ddd': 34, 'pens': 5, 'envelope': 20},'Sidorov': {'aaa': 356},'Ziborov': {'eee': 234}}
```

And I want to print this :

```
{'Ivanov': {'aaa': 52, 'bbb': 3, 'ccc': 45,'envelope': 5,'marker': 3, 'paper': 17},   'Petrov': {'aaa': 9, 'bbb': 7, 'ddd': 34,'envelope': 20 'pens': 5},'Sidorov': {'aaa': 356},'Ziborov': {'eee': 234}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, for each key, I sort its subdictionary.

```
dict_1={'Ivanov': {'aaa': 52, 'bbb': 3, 'ccc': 45, 'paper': 17, 'marker': 3, 'envelope': 5},   'Petrov': {'aaa': 9, 'bbb': 7, 'ddd': 34, 'pens': 5, 'envelope': 20},'Sidorov': {'aaa': 356},'Ziborov': {'eee': 234}} 

def sort(dict_input):
    #Sorting subdictionaries
    dict_output={}
    for i in sorted(dict_input):
        dict_output[i]=dict_input[i]
    return dict_output
        
dict_2={}
for key in sorted(dict_1):
    #For each key, sorting subdictionary
    dict_2[key]=sort(dict_1[key])
print(dict_2)
```